# Could not get unknown property 'runtime' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I've got the error (Could not get unknown property 'runtime' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.) when I followed answer to [how to copy all source jars using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154458/how-to-copy-all-source-jars-using-gradle), added the below code to build.gradle and run that task in IJ IDEA:

```
task copySourceJars( type: Copy ) {
  def sources = configurations.runtime.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.collect { artifact ->
    project.dependencies.create( [
      group: artifact.moduleVersion.id.group,
      name: artifact.moduleVersion.id.name,
      version: artifact.moduleVersion.id.version,
      classifier: 'sources'
    ] )
  }
  from configurations.detachedConfiguration( sources as Dependency[] )
    .resolvedConfiguration.lenientConfiguration.getFiles( Specs.SATISFIES_ALL )
  into file( 'some-directory/' )
}
```

I did a web search for the error but found on stackoverflow only [Gradle - Could not get unknown property 'scm' for configuration container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743263/gradle-could-not-get-unknown-property-scm-for-configuration-container) where it is advised to add configuration like what I did after reading that post:

```
configurations {
    runtime
}
```

After that on task `copySourceJars` run it wrote BUILD SUCCESSFUL, but no files appeared in specific directory on hard drive. Build output for some reason do not list `copySourceJars`:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources]

Gradle Daemon started in 1 s 427 ms
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 9s
4 actionable tasks: 4 up-to-date
```

Then I again chose `run` from IDEA menu and got another error:

> Could not open init remapped class cache for dulrvlqnmf04w7h3gseaejvhm
>   (/Users/user/.gradle/caches/5.2.1/scripts-remapped/ijresolvers_8btlazswoejgb1uwugudd695x/dulrvlqnmf04w7h3gseaejvhm/init3ca90766b0adfce53d4b035e7e9dc5fe).
>
> > Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script '/private/var/folders/g7/2zrjv4hd04v4vkhkbm3stchjwwbz27/T/ijresolvers.gradle'
> >     (/Users/user/.gradle/caches/5.2.1/scripts/dulrvlqnmf04w7h3gseaejvhm/init/init3ca90766b0adfce53d4b035e7e9dc5fe).
> >     BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 57

Am I doing all correctly to download dependancies using IJ IDEA? Maybe that adding configuration `runtime` was not done properly?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/66910991/5158636 I changed runtime to runtimeOnly, though that was as part of an update to Gradle 7, but this seems to be related to Gradle 5.

Answer (score 19):

This is because of the differences between your gradle version and gradle7. From Gradle 6.x, the use of the parameter `configurations.runtime` to get configurations of program execution is disabled. Instead, you can use `configurations.runtimeClasspath` to achieve the same ability.
[Gradle7 docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDlXx.png)
After that, I succeeded in compilitation and get the true constructure of project.

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

[Project Constructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OewhJ.png)

Comment: Gradle 7.5's result: ```unknown property 'runtimeClasspath' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in previous answer(s) support for `runtime` configuration has been stopped `gradle-7.0`, so `configurations.runtime` is not working.

Task `copyAllDependencies` worked for me in `gradle-7.0`.

Here is the example to copy dependencies into `${buildDir}/output/libs`:

Add following to `build.gradle`.

```
task copyAllDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compileClasspath
    into "${buildDir}/output/libs"
}
build.dependsOn(copyAllDependencies)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I am getting `Could not find method from() for arguments [configuration ':compileClasspath'] on task ':copyAllDependencies' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.`

Answer (score 1):

Use `runtimeOnly` as mentioned in the upgrade documentation of gradle:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#sec:configuration_removal